# ag-grid cell renderer that shows data from multiple columns

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to create a cell renderer that will take data from other columns.

For example, each row signifies some piece of data, and users should be able to open it depending on their permissions, and a restricted piece of data should be rendered differently than a non-restricted element. Other columns will have an affect on rendering this one column as well.

I would expect to be able to access the other columns' data using the path `this.params.node.data.restricted`, and this works during a click event, but I can't seem to have access to this data during the rendering phase of the component.

```js
"columnDefs": [
    {
      "field": "id",
      "width": 40,
      "checkboxSelection": true
    },
    {
      "headerName": "Title",
      "field": "docTitle",
      "width": 1580,
      "cellRenderer": "detailViewRenderer"
    }
  ]
```

```js
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {ICellRendererAngularComp} from "ag-grid-angular";

@Component({
  selector: 'detail-view-renderer',
  styles: [``],
  template: `
    <a class="restricted" *ngIf="params.node.data.restricted">{{params.value}}</a>
    <a class="not-restricted" *ngIf="!params.node.data.restricted">{{params.value}}</a>
  `
})
export class DetailViewRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  public params: any;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  constructor() {}

  refresh(): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I think ideally, what I'd like to do is set the columns that will be passed into my renderer and access them in the component somehow as parameters. Is that possible or do we have some other workaround? I see [Full Width Rows](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-full-width-rows/) as an option, but that renders the entire row as one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can access other row properties by using `params.data.restricted`, instead of `params.node.data.restricted`.

For example,

```
method() {
 const detailViewRenderer = params => {
   return `<span>${params.data.restricted}</span>`;
 };


 this.columnDefs: [
    {
      "field": "id",
      "width": 40,
      "checkboxSelection": true
    },
    {
      "headerName": "Title",
      "field": "docTitle",
      "width": 1580,
      "cellRenderer": "detailViewRenderer"
    }
 ]
}
```

[Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/)

Comment: I think I figured it out. For some reason the rows were initializing before the data was available, so the first time it rendered, i get a null pointer exception. Adding some basic `*ngIf="params && params.data"` prevented the exceptions which let me access the data correctly.

Comment: All I needed was params.data to reach the field and it worked. I was using only data or value directly and it didn't work.

Comment: can also try with ({data})

Comment: Also I don't think method() is needed. A const will do.

Answer (score -1):

If you still looking for answer, you could use `rowNode.columnApi.resetColumnState()`

Comment: Column state has nothing to do with the problem I was having. I was writing a cell renderer component that used data from more than one problem. Column state is more related to the column definitions for each column.